# Add affiliates links in WordPress post from multiples websites

Tags: wordpress, affiliate

Is there any plugins (or ways) to add maybe 3 or 4 differents affiliates links in my posts automatically ?
I want to add the logo of the affiliate website with a link to the product. 
I don't know how to do that.
(Sorry for my english i'm french)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable editing PHP, html and css files than you could easily add such functionality yourself via custom fields.

You can add custom fields with product name, link and image url. They can be set as theme options if they are going to be the same or they can be unique per each post if you will assign such custom fields to posts.

Then in single.php template you can output the values and with html markup and some css you can give them any shape and style.

If you don't want to code custom meta boxes for your custom fields yourself, I would recommend Advanced Custom Fields plugin (it has great documentation).